# Using Javascript to change the action of my form depending on the drop-down value selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'd like to dynamically change the action of my form depending on the value selected, but I'm struggling to do so, and other examples haven't helped me much.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="SearchDatbaseForm" method="POST" action="">
  <select id="selectTableDropDown" onchange="gotoPage(JavascriptDatabaseAdvancedSearch.js)"/>
    <option value="null">Choose a class</option>
    <option value="birdTable">Birds</option>
    <option value="insectTable">Insects</option>
    <option value="butterflyTable">Butterflys</option>

   <!-- Search Bar -->
   Search for: <input type="text" name="aSearch"> 
   <!-- Submit Button -->
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("selectTableDropDown").onchange = function() {
  var currentVal = this.value;

  if (currentVal == "BirdDB") {
    document.searchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerBirdDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "InsectDB") {
    document.searchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerInsectDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "ButterflyDB") {
    document.searchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerButterflyDB.php";
  }
}
```

I wanted the user to be able to select either bird, insect or butterfly and depending on what the user selected, a JavaScript function would dynamically change the form action, so before the press submit, it would've changed the file that thy're opening.

I keep running into various errors and I'm not sure how to make it work, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 4 things that'll keep you from your objective:

- I've never seen syntax like this: `onchange="gotoPage(JavascriptDatabaseAdvancedSearch.js)`, so I removed it.

  - If you are trying to find a place for your script,

    - put it before the closing `</body>` tag while developing,
    - then for production, put it in an external file like so: 
      `<script src="https://domain.com/path/to/JavascriptDatabaseAdvancedSearch.js"></script>`
    - place this line either before the closing tag of `</head>` or `</body>`
- the `<select>` element wasn't closed with `</select>` (minor)
- if you use this expression: `document.SearchDatabaseForm.action`, you must give the form the `name="SearchDatabaseForm"` (essential)
- `currentValue` should correspond to the `<option value="....>` (crucial)

  - `var stdd = document.getElementById("selectTableDropDown");`
  - `var currentValue = stdd.options[stdd.selectedIndex].value`

```js
document.getElementById("selectTableDropDown").onchange = function() {
  var stdd = document.getElementById("selectTableDropDown");
  var currentVal = stdd.options[stdd.selectedIndex].value

  if (currentVal == "birdTable") {

    document.SearchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerBirdDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "insectTable") {
    document.SearchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerInsectDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "butterflyTable") {
    document.SearchDatabaseForm.action = "controllerButterflyDB.php";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="SearchDatbaseForm" name="SearchDatabaseForm" method="POST" action="">
  <select id="selectTableDropDown" name="selectTableDropDown">
    <option value="null">Choose a class</option>
    <option value="birdTable">Birds</option>
    <option value="insectTable">Insects</option>
    <option value="butterflyTable">Butterflys</option>
  </select>?

  <!-- Search Bar -->
  Search for:
  <input type="text" name="aSearch">
  <!-- Submit Button -->
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason when I put it into my code, if I put the JavaScript into the head within <Script> tags it doesn't work, but it will at the bottom of my page in the Body section. Is it OK if I just left it there? Thank you for the help, either way

Comment: The reason why is because there's a certain order on loading HTML, CSS, and JS. This [**article**](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) was the best at explaining it to me. IMHO, placing `<script>` at the closing `</body>` tag is definitely the best place to place *small* scripts that are unique to the page. As far as I can remember, there was only one script that wouldn't work at the bottom: JWPlayer. It's faster and more reliable, *but* as far as maintainability and having more than one page, your'e better off using an external file `.js`. Your'e most welcome, sir. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See comments in my code:

```
document.getElementById("selectTableDropDown").onchange = function() {
  var currentVal = this.value;
  var form = document.getElementById('SearchDatbaseForm'); // find form element
  if (currentVal == "birdTable") { // value in your option element is `birdTable` instead of `BirdDB`
    form.action = "controllerBirdDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "insectTable") { // `insectTable` instead of `InsectDB`
    form.action = "controllerInsectDB.php";
  }
  if (currentVal == "butterflyTable") { // `butterflyTable` instead of `ButterflyDB`
    form.action = "controllerButterflyDB.php";
  }
}
```